# App.xaml exception. Provide value on 'System.Windows.Markup.StaticResource' threw an exception

Tags: wpf, xaml, staticresource

I've fund a few other things on this, but none with answers that help. In my App.xaml file I have a load of styles within a resource dictionary. When I run it on a windows 7 machine, it works absolutely perfectly, but when I run it on an XP machine, it crashes with the exception above. Wonder if anyone could help why?

```
<Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
            <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="{Binding Source={x:Static my:Settings.Default}, Path=DefaultFontSize}"/>
            <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="{Binding Source={x:Static my:Settings.Default}, Path=DefaultFontFamily}"/>
        </Style>
```

Also in this file I have a series of ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries, but the issue seems to be with x:Static my:Settings.Default.

Thanks

Comment: this exception generally would pop up when you are trying to access a resource that you havent already declared, are you using a default dll from win 7 that doesnt exist in xp ?

Comment: Why don't you look at the inner exception? It will tell you what is wrong (most of the time).